# Change VPN password from Linux client

Tags: linux, windows, vpn, passwords, networkmanager

I connect to a VPN using NetworkManager on Linux machine. Username/password are those used as Windows credentials.

I want to change the password. In the IT department they say that from Windows it can be done through  ctrl+alt+delete and using domain's user. But I work only from Linux, can this be done from my computer?

Comment: No, there is no known way to change a PPTP password on a remote system in either Linux or Unix (Mac included).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [smbpasswd](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2980/change-windows-domain-password-from-linux)

Usage:

```
smbpasswd -r <domain-server> -U <user name>
Change Windows Domain password from Linux
If you use Linux in a Windows domain and there are N days to expiry, this is how you can change it without resorting to a windows machine.
```

I have not tested this.

Comment: This works. You have to give it PDC (primary domain controller) IP address in `-r` argument. Thanks for your help!